# Fuzz testing library to integrate with testNG for RESTful API automated tesing

Tags: java, automation, fuzzing

We have a RESTful API at our company with custom java SDK for consuming the API. I have unit tests for the SDK which call the API itself, developed with the TestNG framework. 
Is there any good fuzz testing library which can be integrated with testNG and be executed on the already made tests???